# When using Batch file to start a program, it says "Cannot find 'example.exe' "

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, notepad

I am 100% sure that I have the exe application. The exe application is DriverBooster.exe. It will not start the program with the command `

```
@echo off
start DriverBooster.exe
```

`. I searched my computer and found the exact file in C:\Program Files\IObit\Driver Booster, with the exe so then I wrote

```
@echo off
start C:\Program Files\IObit\Driver Booster\DriverBooster.exe
```

`
But it still shows that Windows cannot find the program "DriverBooster.exe", try fixing spelling mistakes. I also checked the spelling and its 100% correct. I am using a batch file and editing it with "notepad" (Yes a regular notepad). Please someone help.I would greatly appricate anyone helping, thank you! [image: This is the application]

Comment: You could do it like: `@Start "" "C:\Program Files\IObit\Driver Booster\DriverBooster.exe"`, or use the system variable, `@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\IObit\Driver Booster\DriverBooster.exe"`. If you open up a Command Prompt window, you can read the usage information for the `start` command by typing `start /?` and pressing the `[ENTER]` key. You will note that it has a `title` option, which is always taken as the first doublequoted string. I have therefore included an empty title, to prevent your doublequoted filepath being mistaken for a title.

Comment: ty compo it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to the space in the file location, try this:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\IObit\Driver Booster\DriverBooster.exe"
```

EDIT: Added extra set of quotes as suggested by Squashman - it has been a while since I've done bash :)

Comment: You also need an empty set of quotes because the `START` command will interpret the first set of quotes as the "TITLE" of the Window.

Comment: Erm..I meant batch...whoops!

Comment: ty so much for your help, it worked!! I started the batch file with that code and then it launched the exe! Ty for your help!